# How to create a simple animation in android

Tags: android, animation, drawable, animationdrawable

I want to know what is the best when I want to create a simple `animation` in `android`, for example if I have a character face and I want to move the eyes fron right to left and so on.

I suggest yo use [AnimationDrawable](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/drawable-animation.html) , is that a good practice ?

At the same time almost I have one animation. for example ,, cat face smiling when touch occurs. But I have many different animations, but at the same time 1 or 2 animations

Comment: It always depends on your actual needs, you didn't provided enough info for this question. There are a lot of different ways to do this, and each one of them is intended for something. How many animations do you have in one moment. If you have more then let's say 10 maybe you would get slow response from AnimationDrawable. If you have only one then go with it :)